# Can I use "has have had" together in a sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, auxiliary-verbs, verb-usage

Can I use *has, have, and had* together in a sentence like,

**Karan says he has have had three "epic fail" relationships in life.**

I've seen this sentence in [The Indian Express](http://indianexpress.com/article/entertainment/bollywood/karan-johar-on-his-love-life-4408717/) and [India Today](http://indiatoday.intoday.in/story/sad-that-love-has-always-been-a-failure-in-my-life-karan/1/826050.html).

A guy has been arguing with me insisting that you can use like that and it's grammatical.

I said it's ungrammatical but he showed the websites above and a few more(of same article).

I still can't understand whether it's grammatical or not. I've never seen such a usage.

Am I right in saying it's ungrammatical? Please someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Maybe it's grammatical in Indian English, but it definitely sounds ungrammatical in other *Englishes*, such as American and British English (as far as I know).

Comment: I think it's archaic; it's no place in modern English.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+have+had&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chas%20have%20had%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Khan On what do you base that? A few contextless spikes in a Google Ngrams graph for "**has have had**"? That structure is completely *legal* in certain contexts. The graph is immaterial to the discussion, and your conclusion is hence spurious.

Comment: @Khan None of the actual citations in your nGram is an instance of a construction *has have had*--they're all false hits where the collocation of the three words is either a list of forms in a grammar book or an accidental sequence which crosses constituent boundaries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *****Karan says he has have had three "epic fail" relationships in life.

The above sentence doesn't appear to be grammatical. I suspect the author wanted to say the following instead:

> Karan says he has had three "epic fail" relationships in (his) life.

---

A "has have had" *cluster* may occur in a sentence such as this one:

> [The medical conditions he **has**] [**have had** an impact on his professional life.]

Note that the part in bold is *an accidental sequence which crosses constituent boundaries*, as per [StoneyB's comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/113516/can-i-use-has-have-had-together-in-a-sentence#comment228565_113516); i.e., it comprises two units, rather than one, which I denoted by using square brackets.

---

Read the following answer/post if you don't know how to construct a perfect tense: [What is the perfect, and how should I use it? § How do I construct a Perfect?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it/13257#13257)

Comment: Oh, the fun you can have with these, especially *sans* punctuation: e.g. *he has have had while she had had had*.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just a typo, where a word got lost:

Karan says he has **to** have had three "epic fail" relationships in life.